# ANT_HOME doesn't match up with ant -version

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, ant

I started out by trying to run ant on a java program in a RH terminal.

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/phuong3/soar/soarRepos2/soar/tools/trunk/build.xml:187: Compiler Adapter 'javac1.6' can't be found.

Total time: 0 seconds
```

I was told that this problem would be fixed if I updated ant from 1.6.5 to 1.7.1.  1.7.1 already exists on the system at /opt/apache-ant-1.7.1/bin.  So I changed ANT_HOME to this directory, and appended it to PATH.  Now the state is:

```
[**** trunk]$ echo $ANT_HOME
/opt/apache-ant-1.7.1/bin
[**** trunk]$ ant -version
Apache Ant version 1.6.5 compiled on August 30 2006
```

So I'm presumably missing a very fundamental step.  Can you tell me what it is?

EDIT: Bump.  I really could use a hint on this.  Is there more information I can provide?  Basically what I need to know is, once I already have the Ant 1.7.1 binaries in the system, and ANT_HOME set to this directory, what else do I have to do to make 1.7.1 be the version that's used?

Comment: Is the old version removed from the PATH? it may still be finding that version first.

Comment: Ahh.  PATH includes /usr/bin, and `which ant' -> /usr/bin/ant.  So the problem's identified, but how do I fix it?  Obviously, I don't want to remove /usr/bin from PATH, right?

Comment: You're supposed to construct an absolute path using `$ANT_HOME/ant` if it's defined, and not rely on a correct `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself.  Explanation to the best of my ability: Since when I typed in `ant`, the OS iterated through PATH until it found a directory which contained an executable called ant, the first one it found was going to be the right one.  The one I wanted it to execute was LAST in the path.  So in bash_profile, instead of `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/apache-ant-1.7.1/bin`, I did `export PATH=/opt/apache-ant-1.7.1/bin:$PATH`.  Now, the desired version of ant shows up first and is the one executed.

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered the same symptoms, but with a different cause.

At some point in the past I must have placed a copy of `ant-1.6.5.jar` in `~/.ant/lib`. This means ant always tried to use that jar. Solution was to remove the jar from `~/.ant/lib`.